# getting a value that is between a from limit and to limit in list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of Gift. I am passing in a value and I want to check if this value best matches one (or first value out of many) from the list of Gift.

```
List<GiftConfig> m_Gifts = new List<GiftConfig>() { 
                new GiftConfig () { Id = 1, From = 5000000, To = 8999999},
                new GiftConfig () { Id = 2, From = 9000000, To = 18999999},
                new GiftConfig () { Id = 3, From = 1900000, To = 25000000},
                new GiftConfig () { Id = 4, From = 35000000, To = 0},
            };
```

Ex: 7000000 => Id = 1
10000000 => Id = 2

Comment: You could do a `.Where()` and put your comparison logic in there.  Perhaps even a `.Single()` (or `.SingleOrDefault()`) if you're sure there should be only one matching element.  That last record might give you problems though, since the range is reversed.

Comment: What's the question? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
var gifts = m_Gifts.Where(x => value >= x.From && (value <= x.To || x.To == 0));
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
int value = 7000000;
GiftConfig gift = m_Gifts.FirstOrDefault(x => value >= x.From && value <= x.To);
// Returns Id 1
value = 10000000;
gift = m_Gifts.FirstOrDefault(x => value >= x.From && value <= x.To);
// Returns Id 2
value = 999999999;
gift = m_Gifts.FirstOrDefault(x => value >= x.From && value <= x.To);
// Returns null (assuming GiftConfig is a class).
```

This will return the first matching gift, or null if there is not one - 'best' is a bit ambiguous. Also a little unsure of what you are expecting to be done with the final record - why is 'To' 0? Is this a special case?

Comment: the final record is 0 because real it is null and i set default is 0